Vscode view changes since last review - just like github
In vscode how to view changes since last review - just like github .
I want to see changes in past few commits combined & not just in a single commit.
I also want to be able mark a file as viewed only for those particular commit. Currently if I mark a file as view in a commit in vscode - it marks the file as viewed overall in all commits.
I use vscode github pull request plugin.
